# Change the table dates from My Account View Subscription in WooCommerce

Tags: php, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

With WooCommerce Subscription plugin specifically, I am encountering difficulty editing the appearance of the "my-account/view-subscription" page. I need to remove the line displaying the "Next Payment Date." Please refer to the attached screenshot for clarity.

[image]

Your guidance on how to accomplish this task would be greatly appreciated.

I received a suggestion to make CSS adjustments, but unfortunately, the provided solution did not yield the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code snippet:

```php
add_filter( 'wcs_subscription_details_table_dates_to_display', 'filter_subscription_details_table_dates' );
function filter_subscription_details_table_dates( $table_dates ) {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('view-subscription') && isset($table_dates['next_payment']) ) {
        unset($table_dates['next_payment']); // Remove "Next payment" row.
    }
    return $table_dates;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Comment: Hello,
and would you be able to advise me how to remove it from the mobile version as well?
Thank you

Comment: I apologize for that. I marked the answer as helpful. It helped me remove the prepayment but only on the desktop version of the site. I would still need help with removing next payment on mobile. Could you advise?

Comment: I just tested, and it works on mobile too… Try to clear your cache. I can't guess why you have this issue.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I asked another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78136761/change-the-table-dates-from-my-account-view-subscription-in-woocommerce-in-mobil